# Why does Ben Halvorson insist upon English?

Tags: the-innocents

In the first scene we see at Sanctum, Sigrid starts speaking in Norwegian, Runa says that Dr. Halvorson requires that everyone talk in English at Sanctum, and that the rules are in place for a reason.

What *is* the reason? We saw that his Norwegian was quite basic some years in the past, but after living in Norway so long, he presumably has had sufficient opportunity to learn it. In any case, while it is surely more convenient for him to speak English, that does not seem like a very serious reason.  Is there some psychological or other justification behind this rule?

Comment: I've not seen it, but is the Sanctum an international organisation? Are there any people there who aren't Norwegian?

Comment: They are all Norwegian, except that Ben might be British.

Comment: Surely that's your answer. He speaks English and is the boss. He doesn't speak excellent Norwegian but they speak excellent English.

Comment: He has had plenty of time to learn Norwegian. I am inclined to think that there is a psychological reason for his insistence, possibly related to his need to feel control, or possibly as part of the treatment program he is running. Keep in mind that he also wants them to speak English to each other, and even when he is not around, and "the rules (plural) are in place for a reason" does not easily lend itself to being interpreted as a mere courtesy to Halvorson.

Comment: Are they being filmed? Also, when your boss tells you to do something, it's not a courtesy.

Comment: He's not their boss, he basically is their psychologist, and he is trying to help them control a supernatural condition/ability, so presumably his insistence on this (as well as his other rules) has a greater purpose. Why not see the show before guessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see a lot of evidence indicating that Ben is running what is, effectively, a cult. For instance, Steinar's friend outright accuses him of being in a cult, and the former offers to donate his house to Sanctum, which is quite typical of cults. June's father also says that Ben is "David Koresh," in reference to the infamous cult leader. In such an organization, a single charismatic leader demands control over the lives of the initiates, who are expected to dedicate the lives to the cult. In exchange, the leader promises the cult various things. In real life, this often includes things like a heavenly reward, but many such organizations often promise members control over their own lives, just as some modern self-help cults do—and just as Ben does.

Now, just as in any cult, the leader employs a variety of means to control the lives of its members. Ben requires the women at Sanctum to wear simple, homemade clothing; to avoid touching each other (or him) regardless of whether there is a risk of shifting or how much progress they have made their therapy sessions; and to avoid leaving the island at all (although there are some reasons for these last two). By making them speak a language other than their own, which he is *quite* insistent upon, Ben does not simply make conversations a tad easier for himself: he also distances them from their past, adds further rigidity to their lives, and adds another arbitrary standard that they can feel guilty about violating. Presumably he justifies these measures as self-discipline to help them bring their abilities under control, but in reality it is just another element of the rules that give him complete control over their lives.